# Is is possible (and how) to have a "virtual" soft link whose value depends on the shell environment?

Tags: linux, bash

The question could probably be reworded. What I would like to have is certain path, say `/workingsrc` to refer to a different real path per shell (bash) instance simultaneously.

So in an instance of bash I can do `ls /workingsrc` and get the contents of `/foo/bar` and in another instance that is running at the same time in the same machine do `ls /workingsrc` and get the contents of `/foo/zoo`.

Do you know if there is a way to do this? I'm using linux and bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant symlinks is what you want, but are only on *BSD and AFS filesystem. Working with environment variables is much easier (see Hyppy response).

Comment: You are right, this is exactly what I was looking for. Too bad they are not available in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do this with environment variables. For example:
Shell 1:

```
WORKINGSRC=/foo/bar
ls $WORKINGSRC
```

Shell 2:

```
WORKINGSRC=/foo/zoo
ls $WORKINGSRC
```

Back on shell 1:

```
ls $WORKINGSRC
```

You should still see /foo/bar on shell 1, even after setting the variable to a different value in shell 2.

Comment: You could probably add an alias to this so you don't distract people with the $

Comment: An alias doesn't expand within a command unless it begins with the alias, though. For example, if you set $WORKINGSRC to an alias called aliaswrksrc, then "ls aliaswrksrc" won't work. You'd have to make a separate alias for each command you want to do, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Okay, i meant it's set to the correct value when you log into the shell. So as part of .bash_profile you do: export WORKING_DIR=/var/tmp; alias cdwork="cd $WORKING_DIR". Then cdwork will take me to what WORKING_DIR is set to at login to the shell time.

Comment: yes, currently I am using a env var with the work dir path in it, and a function that sets its value and updates all depending env vars. I also have `shopt -s cdable_vars` in my .bashrc so that I can do `cd workingsrc` anywhere and get to `$workingsrc`. I was looking for a *next step* from this setup.